# Is it possible to conditionally checkout repository branch in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this pipeline which has a parameter `primary_region`. I would like to conditionally checkout the `Export` repository's branch depending on the value that is provided to that parameter.

For example, I tried to add conditional expressions over the `ref` attribute of `repository`:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: primary_region
    displayName: Primary region (or environment)
    type: string
    default: main
    values:
      - main
      - qa
      - production
      - dr

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Export
      type: git
      name: Export.Deployment
      ${{ if eq(parameters.primary_region, 'dr') }}:
        ref: 'production'
      ${{ if ne(parameters.primary_region, 'dr') }}:
        ref: ${{ parameters.primary_region }}

trigger: none

jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: Disaster Recovery region switch
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: Export
      ...
```

so that when the `primary_region` is set to `dr` I will use the `production` branch for the `checkout` step. And in case the parameter does not equal `dr` I will use whatever value is provided in the parameter.

However, it looks like those conditional expressions are not allowed there as I am getting this error when I try to run the pipeline:

```
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 44, Col: 7): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 46, Col: 7): A template expression is not allowed in this context
```

Comment: You *really* shouldn't have branches for different environments in Git.

Comment: Apologies for taking long to respond. What approach would you suggest instead? Using DevOps "environments" feature?

Comment: Start with a standard branching model like GitFlow or GitHubFlow, then make tweaks depending on your application's business context and requirements.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I wish we could adopt this in our team. However, those branching methods are more suited for small teams who release frequently.  As our team release at a slower phase, I think having branches for environments make more sense.

Comment: The frequency of release doesn't change anything. Branching per environment is a generally bad practice. The builds that you deploy to your QA environment and test should be the same build that you ultimately deploy to production. Otherwise, why did you bother testing? You invalidate all of the testing you've done every time you do a new build.

Comment: That's a good point. We generally promote changes from main -> QA -> Prod by cherry-picking or branch merges (e.g. merging `main` to `QA`). However, each branch can have branch-specific changes (i.e. for the specific environment). I agree with your point that it won't be the same build we tested in QA that would be deployed to Prod. 

I have thought about proposing  GitFlow or GitHubFlow to our team before so maybe now is the time. That would definitely simplify our workflow.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a mess. Some variety of GitFlow in conjunction with feature toggling to eliminate the need for cherry-picking would make life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
trigger: none
 
parameters:
- name: primary_region
  displayName: Primary region (or environment)
  type: string
  default: main
  values:
    - main
    - qa
    - production
    - dr

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: DR
  displayName: Disaster Recovery region switch
  steps:
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.primary_region, 'dr') }}:
      - checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepoA@production
    - ${{ if ne(parameters.primary_region, 'dr') }}:
      - checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo@${{parameters.primary_region}}
```

Reference [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It took me a while but I finally got around to test if that will work and it does as per the official documentation you have provided. Thus, I am accepting your answer. 

I did not know you can provide a URL to the `checkout` step.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be literally a YAML "checkout" step, but you can use a script step which scripts actual git commands to check out a repo into your pipeline working folder.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That would work :) I will try what Sibtain has suggested first as his approach does not require too many "custom" changes.